# Upgrading to PHP 5.3 in .htaccess causes browser to download file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm helping someone out with a Wordpress 3.8 install on an older Hostgator account that uses PHP 5.2.17.  I'd like to make use of some plugins which require 5.3+ .

[According to Hostgator docs](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/php-5-3) you should be able to simply add:

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

to your .htaccess file and get the desired result.

However, after adding these lines to the top or bottom of /public_html/.htaccess I get prompted to download a file in my browser when trying to visit the site:

[image]

Is there something obvious that could be causing this?

Comment: Are you actually using HostGator? Those docs are specific to their servers.

Comment: The person I'm helping said it was HostGator.  Right now the site fires up from an IP address with a ~sitename so like http://111.11.111.1111/~sitename .  When I put the IP address into http://www.whoishostingthis.com/ it says Unified Layer which I believe is really just HostGator

Comment: I had the same issue with HostGator :: I had to undo all changes I made to .htaccess then contact HostGator support they will upgrade it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me so many times.. just check you have this on your .htaccess (When your files are uploaded to Hostgator)

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

and be shure you have the same thing, but commented... using # on the .htaccess lines for your locakhost (because you must have already php 5.3 or later)

```
# Use PHP 5.3
#AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

This fixed me the same issue you had, but in my local.. because i can't see your http://******** i don't know if that was on your local
Best regards. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got more clarification on the hosting environment.  It is a HostGator VPS, which the docs state you need to submit a ticket - and not edit htaccess - to upgrade PHP.